# Is there a script/code to add link attributes to many links at once?

Tags: javascript, html

I just noticed my outgoing links do not have the rel="nofollow" link attribute.  Is there a way to add this to all my outgoing links?  I'm not the programmer I'm the website owner.  Thanks to those that reply.

PS/
I'm looking for a simple solution I can do. Like I mention before I'm not the web developer I'm the site owner and cannot afford to pay right now. But I do have a basic knowledge of html. There are more than 700 links all different and they seem to be generated with JavaScript. I cannot see the links looking at the index file but can see them in the MySQL database.

FOUND SOLUTION:  Thanks to those that replied.

I updated the links in the database using this query:
UPDATE table_name SET field_name = replace(field_name, 'unwanted_text', 'wanted_text');

Comment: if those links share a common piece of string you can use the texteditor find and replace, adding the new attribute

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  There are 700 links all different.

Answer (score 1):

You are not giving us much to go on, but heres a way you could do it with generally any text editor that support Find and Replace:

Search for the string `<a href="` and replace it with `<a rel="nofollow" href="`. That should sort most of the links on your page that are correctly structured. This is not the best way (you would want you `href` to be the first attribute but since semantics are probably not that important here this will work).

There are many (and I mean many_ other ways to do this, using regexes to find the string and replace them, but I'm thinking you are searching for the simpelest solution.

Comment: I'm looking for a simple solution I can do.  Like I mention before I'm not the web developer I'm the site owner and cannot afford to pay right now.  But I do have a basic knowledge of html.  There are more than 700 links all different and they seem to be generated with JavaScript.  I cannot see the links looking at the index file but can see them in the MySQL database.

Comment: Would it be possible to do the search and replace in the MySQL database?  If so, what would be the code/query for that?  Thanks.

Comment: @user1667057 Thats a bit harder as now there are a lot of variables you want to contend with. Is the site written in PHP? Does it use wordpress...? Is it custom made? Changing links like that involves a lot. If it was simple changing a text file, easy. Searching and replacing in a database is virtually impossible unless you tell us exactly what tables you have, what columns, where the links are... Also, as a developer I think it unfair to do something like that for you when you admit you dont even want to pay for such service. This site is for learning, not cheap labour. Sorry.

Comment: Just found this query online:  ' UPDATE `table_name`
 SET `field_name` = replace(same_field_name, 'unwanted_text', 'wanted_text')' Would this work?

Comment: If all your `urls` are in a single field that could work yes. BUT be carefull when you work with your mySQL database as a mistake could remove all your field data. (If the field is not found, or empty, or... Too many possibilities). Even fi you'de contact the original devleoper and give him a tenner for such an easy thing. I'm wondering though, if your site uses a database it might have an admin, and you might be able to directly edit HTML in there. Most WYSIWYG editors do.

Comment: I'm the only one that has access to the database.  Yes, all the urls are in one column of the table.  There are values in each column or field.  So no field is empty.  The url is inside this field.  The files are .php and not all links appear on the editor.

Comment: I did contact the original developer, he is a friend of mine, but he has to much work to work on the site right now.  The above query worked.  So thanks, you gave me the idea.

Comment: @user1667057 Good, happy it worked for you. When I started out working with mySQL with my first babysteps I was making mistakes in queries all the time and have learned that they can be quite dangerous,c ertainly for live databases. You should have exported a backup first! But yeah, good.

Comment: Agreed.  I tested with one record first and it worked perfectly.  I knew all the urls where constructed in the same fashion.  So I gave it a go and it worked.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add in a jQuery script reference in your page if it is not there already for this solution, but this will add rel="nofollow" to every `<a>` link on the current page. Included is Google's hosted jQuery library:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("a").attr("rel", "nofollow");
</script>
```

Comment: I thought of this as well, but since the Googlebot doesn't execute Javascript when it scans your pages, this would have no effect on the `nofollow` status.

Comment: What do you mean? Would the solution to that be to link to a local jQuery library then?

Comment: Bots don't execute javascript (most of the time), so adding it wouldn't show up for google like that. It would for a user, but `nofollow` is mostly useful for search engines.